# Como fazer insert em tabelas com relacionamento muitos para muitos?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net, sql-insert

Estou com uma duvida de como vou fazer o *insert* com relacionamento `n:n`

minhas tabelas são:

```
Recibo
Analise
Analise_Recibo (recibo_id, analise_id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para usar este código precisa carregar o *namespace* apropriado:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

O segredo é pegar o último ID inserido após cada `INSERT` com a propriedade `LastInsertedId` para usar na terceira tabela. Ideia geral de código para ilustrar (provavelmente precisa de adaptação para ir para produção, principalmente do tratamento da exceção):

```
try {
    var connection = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;userid=user;password=1234;database=banco"); 
    connection.Open();
    var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

    var command = new MySqlCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.Transaction = transaction;

    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Recibo (ID, AlgumCampo) VALUES (DEFAULT, ?campo1)";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?campo1", dadoDoRecibo);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    var idRecibo = command.LastInsertedId;
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Analise (ID, algumCampo) VALUES (DEFAULT, ?campo1)";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?campo1", dadoDaAnalise);
    var idAnalise = command.LastInsertedId;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Analise_Recibo (ID, recibo_id, analise_id) VALUES (DEFAULT, ?idRecibo, ?idAnalise)";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?idRecibo", idRecibo);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?idAnalise", idAnalise);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    transaction.Commit();

} catch (MySqlException ex) {
    try { 
        transaction.Rollback();                
    } catch (MySqlException ex) {
        Console.WriteLine("Erro: {0}",  ex.ToString());                
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Erro: {0}",  ex.ToString());
} finally {
    if (connection != null) {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ADO.NET/InsertNToM.cs).

Comment: cheguei a quase isso... vou colocar um FOR para inserir os valores em um array que armazena as analises selecionadas....

Answer (score 0):

Para INSERT em Analise_Recibo sao necessarios as chaves de ReciboId e uma AnaliseID , voce precisa remodelar sua tabela Analise_Recibo para conter foreign keys de ReciboId e AnaliseID:

```
Recibo       Analise_Recibo    Analise
==========   ============      ======
ReciboID     Recibo_ID         AnaliseID
             Analise_ID
```

Para insert segue:

```
insert into dbo.Analise_Recibo (ReciboId, AnaliseId) 

select
  u.ReciboId,
  r.AnaliseId,

from dbo.Recibo u

inner join dbo.Analise r

on r.AnaliseId = u.ReciboId
```