# Gerar a chave primária na aplicação ou mantê-la como auto incrementável?

Tags: c#, .net, banco-de-dados

Devo definir a chave primária da minha tabela como `auto_increment` ou defini-la como numérico, gerando a chave dentro da minha aplicação?

#### Contextualização

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em C# e testando-a em um banco de dados Access, para depois passá-la para um banco MySQL.

Um problema que me passou pela cabeça foi:

1) Com uma chave do tipo `auto_increment`, para saber a chave primária do registro que salvei, vou ter que ir no banco e buscá-la após ter salvo os dados.

2) Com uma chave manual (criada pela aplicação), não vou precisar fazer o passo 1), pois já vou ter criado a chave primária dentro da aplicação antes de salvar os dados.

Comment: _"Com uma chave do tipo auto_increment, para saber a chave primária do registro que salvei, vou ter que ir no banco e buscá-la após ter salvo os dados."_ - normalmente esse valor é devolvido pelo DB de maneira segura, sem "custo" significativo, quando a aplicação faz nova inserção. No caso do 2 você não tem o mínimo controle de não criar chaves repetidas se sua mais de uma aplicação for executada, ou se sua aplicação tiver mais de uma thread alterando o DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Devo definir a chave primária da minha tabela como `auto_increment` ou defini-la como numérico, gerando a chave dentro da minha aplicação?

No banco de dados sempre.

> 1) Com uma chave do tipo `auto_increment`, para saber a chave primária do registro que salvei, vou ter que ir no banco e buscá-la após ter salvo os dados.

Perfeito, é assim que deve ser. [Algo assim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/44655/101). É simples, confiável e rápido.

Na pergunta original falava em pegar o último ID criado e incrementá-lo manualmente. Não é fácil fazer isso certo e pode causar uma penalidade de tempo. Se fizer errado pode ter uma [condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101).

> 2) Com uma chave manual (criada pela aplicação), não vou precisar fazer o passo 1), pois já vou ter criado a chave primária dentro da aplicação antes de salvar os dados.

E pode criar uma chave que já foi criada por outro cliente. Não faça isso.

Até pode fazer se [usar GUID ou algo parecido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21907/101), mas é uma complicação que só compensa em casos bem específicos. Não é fácil fazer certo.